# Trouble loading js

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry in advance if this is simple or if it just can't be done. Basically, I am trying to load an age verification js on my site, but I am trying to chose between different pages depending on the legal drinking age in different countries.

If I load the script simply, it works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://av.ageverify.co/jsfr/singlemalt.18.js"></script>
```

However, if I trying to do any sort of modification to this script, it won't load at all. For example, if I try to set the src to a variable (that I would call in a different script, it fails to load).

```
<script>
    url = "https://av.ageverify.co/jsfr/singlemalt.18.js";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=url></script>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

EDITED:

Additional info: 
I tried to use getScript as people have suggested but also had issues with it:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.getScript("https://av.ageverify.co/jsfr/singlemalt.18.js");

</script>
```

or this method:

```
function loadJs() {
  var url = "https://av.ageverify.co/jsfr/singlemalt.18.js";
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = url;
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

This last one seems to work with other simple scripts, but maybe this particular script is looking for some sort of browser condition? Any suggestions on how to figure that out or what to look for? There should be an age verification page that pops up, asking your age.

Comment: In html, doesn't exists variables, you must make it by javascript

Comment: The `src` of a `<script>` tag *needs* to be a URL, you cannot use a variable there.

Comment: @RocketHazmat you can't use a variable in nowhere on HTML language. `:)`

Comment: src propery of a script tag doest allow variable usage.
Use Jquery GetScript Method. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: @LütfullahKus: He may not be using jQuery in his page.

Comment: yes, I tried that but still no luck:    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $().getScript("https://av.ageverify.co/jsfr/singlemalt.18.js");

    </script>

Comment: @JakeM: It's `$.getScript(url);`,  *not* `$().getScript(url);`.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work with correcting my getScript code. I wonder if there is something specific with this .js file that doesn't like being modified somehow?

Answer (score 2):

HTML tags do not understand variables.  You need to use a URL for the `src` attribute.  HTML has no idea what your JavaScript variables are.

If you want to load the `.js` file this way, you need to use JavaScript.  What you can do is create a new `<script>` tag then append it to the page.

```
var url = "https://av.ageverify.co/jsfr/singlemalt.18.js";

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = url;

document.head.appendChild(script);
```

If you are using jQuery, this is basically what `$.getScript` does.

```
var url = "https://av.ageverify.co/jsfr/singlemalt.18.js";

$.getScript(url);
```

Comment: Neither of those seems to be working for me. I wonder if there is a specific issue with this .js code? It seems to work when I put other .js modules in.

Comment: Any idea why this wouldn't work for a specific script?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  What happens when you try to load it this way?  Do you see any messages (errors) in the console?  What is this script supposed to do?

Comment: I tried to load it this way in a jsFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/v4z3kk4z/) and it seemed to work.

Comment: I don't see any errors, but the age verification page doesn't pop up. It should load like this page does: [link](http://www.tambour-original.com/)

Comment: For example, when putting it directly into html as in this fiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/sLc6dLL8/ ] it works, but not in the fiddle that you made, at least for me...

Comment: @JakeM: It may be something in the script itself.  I can't tell since the `.js` file is a garbled mess.